# can't run ScalaIDE in a XP without networks

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

Recently I would like to move my dev env into my company's standard virtual XP without internet connection. But my Scala dev env is broken. I test ScalaIDE from typesafe by unzip and copy into virtual XP. And, I tried install scala plugins on a pure Eclipse and copy it into that virtual XP. Both of these two approaches were broken.
Anyone know why? 
My notebook with internet run ScalaIDE very well. I have test in a virtual XP with internet , thru virtualbox. The ScalaIDE works well. But in that virtual XP without internet, it seems that all scala plugins are disappear from Eclipse but files in plugins/features. I can't open Scala perspective, can't fint scala in preferences.
What happens?

Thanks!

[update] the TypeSafe's ScalaIDE can't run in an environment without any networks, intranet  or internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather of your question, you have an installation problem rather than a build problem. Building may be problematic if you have dependencies that are unavailable offline, but installing Scala IDE should work.

The [Scala-IDE website](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html) offers a zipped update site for download for every release. The direct URL for the latest version is [here](http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/update-site.zip).

You need to make this file available to the offline OS you're using. If you unzip it, you should be able to point to the decompressed result as a local update-site and choose the plugins you may want to install. More simply, you can also try to drag and drop that zip into the installation dialog of Eclipse.